# How to select every 2nd node in XSL

Tags: xslt

Below is an example of my code. The item tag loop through my code many times.

```
<item>
    <title>Secret Court Palace Gardens</title>`enter code here`
    <link>htt://www.flickr.com/photos/aataka/954934842/in/pool-1540822@N20</link>
    <description>
        <p>
            <a href="htt://www.flickr.com/people/aataka/">aataka</a> has added a photo to the pool:</p>
        <p>
            <a href="htt://www.flickr.com/photos/aataka/954934842/" title="Hampton Court Palace Gardens">
                <img src="htt://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/954934842_a38fca47c7_m.jpg" width="240" height="107" alt="Secret Court Palace Gardens" />
            </a>
        </p>
    </description>
</item>
```

I need to select the url value in the 'img src' tag inside the 2nd 'a' tag. I tried something like below but didn't work. Can anyone help? Thanks very much.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="htt://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:media="htt://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item/description/p[2]/*">
        <img src="{a/@href}" style="margin:5px 5px" />
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you show us the outer tags of your XML (the `rss` and `channel`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For input xml (I correct some evident mistakes like "htt"->"http" or semicolons in `<rss>` opening tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:creativeCommons="cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/creativeCommonsRssModule.html" xmlns:flickr="urn:flickr:user">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Secret Court Palace Gardens</title>
            <link>htt://www.flickr.com/photos/aataka/954934842/in/pool-1540822@N20</link>
            <description>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/people/aataka/">aataka</a> has added a photo to the pool:</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/aataka/954934842/" title="Hampton Court Palace Gardens">
                        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/954934842_a38fca47c7_m.jpg" width="240" height="107" alt="Secret Court Palace Gardens"/>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

following xslt should work

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:media="htt://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item/description/p[position() mod 2 = 0]//img">
                    <img src="{@src}" style="margin:5px 5px"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces following output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/954934842_a38fca47c7_m.jpg" style="margin:5px 5px">
    </body>
</html>
```

I think `p[position() mod 2 = 0]` should make a job as far as I guess you want to select every second `<p>` element and iterate through all contained `<img>`.

Comment: Hi Jirka. Thanks a lot for your reply, unfortunately, it still didn't work. For "rss/channel", it is actually part of my xml. I just didn't put it in, to make the code look simpler. Hope there are other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Could you concretize what "didn't work" means in more details? And you should also add the whole input xml and the expected output.

Comment: What happned was that nothing showed up, the screen was empty. I would like to show all images in the output using the urls in the 'img src' tag. As for the code will try and edit at the top. Thanks.

Comment: As for the code it is to:

<!-- add at top -->
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/creativeCommonsRssModule.html"
xmlns:flickr="urn:flickr:user" >
<channel>


<!-- add after </item> tag -->
</channel>

</rss>

Comment: Hi Jirka, thanks for trying again. Unfortunately it still didn't work. There is an a tag before the img tag. I have tried to change the path myself, but still didn't quite work. Thanks.